# how can i control Nodejs server app by internet

Tags: node.js, websocket, ffmpeg, jsmpeg

I have deploy a node js app on a windows server that decode my ip cam by ffmpeg and jsmpeg that working very well .

On client side i can call the live cam rtsp stream by websocket on my phone .

What i want to do is to control app.js from my phone to stop or restart the app.js

any help is welcom